# Parse Android notifications: how do you set the small notification icon on Parse v1.1?

Tags: android, parse-platform

how do you set setSmallIcon() for a notification on an older version of Parse? (1.1)
Or at least before PushService.setDefaultPushCallback() was deprecated?

I tried setting

```
<meta-data android:name="com.parse.push.notification_icon" android:resource="@drawable/icon"/>
```

in the manifest but that did not work.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know after which version `ParsePushBroadcastReceiver` class exists but you can Inherit that class and override `getSmallIconId` function to replace small icon

Answer (score 0):

Seems that there was no direct way of setting custom icon at that time - it used an app icon for notification. 
But you can write your own PushReceiver, which in `onReceive()` will spawn your own Notifications, where you will have full control over Notification Behavior